# Generating attributes in an automatic way with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, features, qgis-custom-function

I want to autogenerate IDs while I create new features. So every time I create a new point, its ID will increase by 1 like the following:

```
Feature 1: id 1
Feature 2: id 2
Feature 3: id 3
```

How can I attack this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you *right-click* your layer and go to `Properties > Fields` then click the `Text Edit`, you can set **Default values** (either by typing in a value or using an expression) which will appear in the attribute table automatically.

Unfortunately, using an expression like `$rownum` (which should get you unique ids for your features) does not work (my guess is because the feature has to be committed first?). But we can create a function which counts the number of features made and adds 1. You can access the **Function Editor** as shown in the image:

[image: Function Editor]

Then in the Function Editor, create a new file or edit an existing one and use the following code:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def update(feature, parent):
    layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
    x = layer.featureCount()
    return x + 1
```

Click *Load* then go to the **Expression** tab next to it and insert the expression:

```
update()
```

Then click *OK* and you should see a preview value:

[image: Preview]

Click *OK*, *Apply* etc and now hopefully when you create a feature, it will automatically create a unique id in your chosen field.

Comment: I thinkt the featurecount is not very reliable for getting unique values.let's say you have currently 20 features and the update()-function returns the value 21. after that i delete one other feature in the layer and create a new one... this new feature will also get the value 21. I'd rather calculate the max value of the column and add +1

Answer (score 6):

You can use [the plugin "AutoFields"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AutoFields/) for Automatic attribute updates when creating or modifying vector features

Answer (score 3):

I think you can not set default values when creating a new feature but you could try the following work around:

- when done creating your features go to the attribute table
- Go to the field calculator and create a new column called `id` with type Int
- As value insert  `@row_number` which will yield unique vales according to the row number